# My symbol column file size in partitioned table is unusually large -- why would that be?

Tags: kdb, database-partitioning

I've just built my first proper q/kdb+ database with splayed and partitioned tables. Everything is going fine, but I just noticed that my symbol `s` column file size is unusually large. Here is what I can see from the OS and from inside q:

```
# ls -latr 2017.10.30/ngbarx
total 532
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  24992 Apr 17 20:53 vunadj
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  24992 Apr 17 20:53 v
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 300664 Apr 17 20:53 s
...

q)meta ngbarx
c     | t f a
------| -----
date  | d    
s     | s   p
v     | e    
vunadj| e    
...

q)get `:2017.10.30/ngbarx/s
`p#`sym$`A`AA`AACG`AADI`AADR`AAIC`AAIC-B`AAL`AAM-A`AAMC`AAME`AAOI`AAON`AAP`AA..

q)-22!get `:2017.10.30/ngbarx/v
24990
q)-22!get `:2017.10.30/ngbarx/s
28678
q)all (get `:2017.10.30/ngbarx/s) in sym
1b
q)count sym
62136
```

So comparing the real-type `v` column with the symbol-type `s` column, I see from ls that the symbol column is more than 10x the size, even though the internal size in bytes is similar and everything seems properly encoded in the `sym` file.

Is this expected behavior? Or am I doing something wrong that could be fixed?

UPDATE: I have not used compression, and have written the files using the magical function `.Q.dcfgnt`, which can be viewed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60694946/need-to-explain-the-kdb-q-script-to-save-partitioned-table). Well, a slightly modified version, I noticed that this function as is also saved a `date` file in the directory, even though the column should be virtual, so I did some hacking in `k` (I'm not very good at it) and updated the inner function `.Q.dpfgnt` to this ...

```
k){[d;p;f;g;n;t]if[~&/qm'r:+en[d]t;'`unmappable];
 {[d;g;t;i;x]@[d;x;g;t[x]i]}[d:par[d;p;n];g;r;<r f]'{x@&~x=`date}(!r);
 @[;f;`p#]@[d;`.d;:;f,r@&~f=r:{x@&~x=`date}(!r)];n}
```

Comment: I think we need to know a bit more about how this was written down in the first place. Also, stock question: I'm guessing compression settings were not used?

Comment: @user20349 Thanks for responding -- I've updated my question (at the bottom). Thanks! :)

Comment: I don't think modifying `.Q.dpfgnt` is a good idea....the reason it wrote a date file to the directory is likely because you had a date column in the table you told it to write down. A better approach is to delete any column called `date` before you write to disk, and let the database generate the virtual date column like you said

Comment: @terrylynch I can't delete the `date` column and still use `.Q.dcfgnt` as this function uses the date column to do the partition. See `.Q.dcfgnt` here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60694946/need-to-explain-the-kdb-q-script-to-save-partitioned-table

Comment: Then the problem is with that custom function that somebody wrote, it's not a standard or supported function. It allows for two date columns when it shouldn't. You could modify it to delete the date column prior to writing down, maybe something like ```k)dcfgnt:{[d;c;f;g;n;t]*p dpfgnt[d;;f;g;n]'![;();0b;1#(`;c)`date=c]'?[t;;0b;()]',:'(=;c;)'p:?[;();();c]?[t;();1b;(,c)!,c]}``` but that function is becoming a bit of a monstrosity then and I wouldn't recommend using it to be honest

Comment: @terrylynch yep yep, I get you, I basically did the same thing -- simply skipping writing the `date` column in the inner function rather than deleting it in the outer function. Hah yes a bit of a monstrosity, but I guess my `k` skills are improving :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Applying the parted attribute is not free and requires storage. It is usually not that costly but looking at your sample output of s, it doesn't look suitable for parting as does not contain repeating values:

```
q)get `:2017.10.30/ngbarx/s
`p#`sym$`A`AA`AACG`AADI`AADR`AAIC`AAIC-B`AAL`AAM-A`AAMC`AAME`AAOI`AAON`AAP`AA..
```

See below tables created to illustrate the issue:

```
/ no part - 16 distinct syms
t1:([]s:100000?`1;v:100000?2e)

/ part - 16 distinct syms
t2:update `p#s from `s xasc ([]s:100000?`1;v:100000?2e)

/ no part - 99999 distinct syms
t3:([]s:100000?`8;v:100000?2e)

/ part - 99999 distinct syms
t4:update `p#s from `s xasc ([]s:100000?`8;v:100000?2e)
```

The difference in size is insignificant between t1 and t2 with the parted attribute(`804096 -> 804664`). However, when the number of distinct syms / parts becomes very large, the storage cost is very large. (`804096  -> 4749872`)

```
ls | xargs ls -latr
t1:
total 1180
-rw-r--r-- 1 matmoore matmoore     12 Apr 19 10:28 .d
-rw-r--r-- 1 matmoore matmoore 804096 Apr 19 10:28 s
-rw-r--r-- 1 matmoore matmoore 400016 Apr 19 10:28 v
drwxr-xr-x 1 matmoore matmoore   4096 Apr 19 10:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 matmoore matmoore   4096 Apr 19 10:28 ..

t2:
total 1180
-rw-r--r-- 1 matmoore matmoore     12 Apr 19 10:28 .d
-rw-r--r-- 1 matmoore matmoore 804664 Apr 19 10:28 s
-rw-r--r-- 1 matmoore matmoore 400016 Apr 19 10:28 v
drwxr-xr-x 1 matmoore matmoore   4096 Apr 19 10:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 matmoore matmoore   4096 Apr 19 10:28 ..

t3:
total 1180
-rw-r--r-- 1 matmoore matmoore     12 Apr 19 10:28 .d
-rw-r--r-- 1 matmoore matmoore 804096 Apr 19 10:28 s
-rw-r--r-- 1 matmoore matmoore 400016 Apr 19 10:28 v
drwxr-xr-x 1 matmoore matmoore   4096 Apr 19 10:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 matmoore matmoore   4096 Apr 19 10:28 ..

t4:
total 5032
-rw-r--r-- 1 matmoore matmoore      12 Apr 19 10:28 .d
drwxr-xr-x 1 matmoore matmoore    4096 Apr 19 10:28 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 matmoore matmoore 4749872 Apr 19 10:28 s
-rw-r--r-- 1 matmoore matmoore  400016 Apr 19 10:28 v
drwxr-xr-x 1 matmoore matmoore    4096 Apr 19 10:28 .
```

I would also question if this column should be a symbol. If 62k is the size of your sym file with just one date created then you should be careful that you are going to end up creating a bloated sym file. If you have a full history from 2017.10.30 and the sym file is still 62k, then it's fine but if you are adding that many new symbols each day, the sym file will quickly spiral out of control.

Comment: Spot on! Removing or substituting the `p` attribute either with no attribute or the `s` attribute drops the size from 300k to 54k. I guess I'll keep the `s` since that one is free, and this is daily bar data.
Thanks for the tip on the sym file -- I've data since 2012 from 3 data sources, plus some fundamentals classification tables where the stock types and subtypes I've included as symbols as they repeat -- it mostly stopped growing.