# Does q/kdb+ ever act asynchronously when synchronously instructed to write tables to disk?

Tags: kdb, database-partitioning

I've had a strange bug pop up -- when I write to a partitioned table, then immediately after  do a select on that same table, I get an error like:

`./2018.04.23/ngbarx/cunadj. OS reports: Operation not permitted`.

This error does not appear if, after writing the table, I wait a few seconds. This to me seems like pointing towards there being a caching situation, where q responds before an operation is complete, but afaik everything I am doing should be synchronous.

I would love to understand what I am doing wrong / what is causing this error exactly / which commands are executing asynchronously.

The horrible details:

- Am writing from Python connected to q synchronously using the `qpython3` package
- The q session is launched with slaves i.e. `-s 4`
- To write the partitioned table, I am using the unofficial function `.Q.dcfgnt` which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60694946/need-to-explain-the-kdb-q-script-to-save-partitioned-table)
- I write to a q session that was initialized with a database directory as is usual when dealing with partitioned tables
- After writing the table with `.Q.dcfgnt`, but before doing the `select`, I also do `` .Q.chk`:/db/; system"l /db/"; .Q.cn table `` in that order, just to be sure the table is up and ready to use in the q session. These might be both overkill and in the wrong order, but I believe they are all synchronous calls afaik, please correct me if I am wrong.
- The trigger to the error is a `10#select from table`; I understand
  why this is a bad idea to do in general on a partitioned table, but
  also from my understanding it shouldn't be triggering the particular error that I am getting.

Comment: A few ideas: 1. Are you sure that that exact column/file exists and is well formed? 2. If you select all dates then you're pulling in a lot of files but you could in theory be hitting an open-file limit from the operating system (on linux this would be `ulimit`). Or perhaps you're hitting some other restriction in `ulimit`. Though that wouldn't explain why you can do it seconds later. But in general no, kdb isn't doing anything weird under the covers but that doesn't mean that your filesystem isn't. In general you should be able to write and then query.

Comment: What filesystem are you writing to? Is the read coming from the same process? If the filesystem is distributed or network-based, there could be all kinds of CAP-based limitations here.

Comment: @user20349 local and linux for the most time. I guess I can add a `sync` system call after each write just to be sure...